# Programmatically craft Tailwind classes with Vue

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I Just want to have dynamic tailwind classes values that changes when change a data value, it is possible to do it using tailwind?

In my example I have a double side menus and a main content, I want to set the menus width and programmatically change the margins that have the main content.

I don't know why but tailwind doesn't apply my crafted classes even if in the browser shows the right class in the div element.

---

### Left side menu:

(right is equal)

```html
<nav
   class="fixed overflow-x-scroll bg-gray-700 top-16 h-screen"
   :class="classes.leftSidebar"
   >
   <h1 class="text-xl text-center font-bold pt-5">Menu</h1>
   <ul class="list-none text-white text-center">
      <li class="my-8">
         <a href="#">Teams</a>
      </li>
      <li class="my-8">
         <a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="my-8">
         <a href="#">Favourites</a>
      </li>
      <li class="my-8">
         <a href="#">Notifications</a>
      </li>
      <li class="my-8">
         <a href="#">Members</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

### Content:

```html
<main :class="classes.main">
    <slot></slot>
</main>
```

### Script:

```js
data() {
        return {
            showingNavigationDropdown: false,
            sidebar_left_w: 64,
            sidebar_right_w: 64,
        }
    },

    computed: {
        classes() {
            return {
                leftSidebar: `w-[${this.sidebar_left_w}rem]`,
                rightSidebar: `w-[${this.sidebar_right_w}rem]`,
                main: [`mr-[${this.sidebar_right_w}rem]`, `ml-[${this.sidebar_left_w}rem]`],
            }
        }
    },
```

I also tried `` leftSidebar: `w-${this.sidebar_left_w}`, `` but same results

Comment: A switch statement is the only answer because we cannot craft tailwind classes, strings must be unbroken. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is not possible with Tailwind CSS

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don't construct class names dynamically**

```html
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
<!-- This will not work -->
```

> In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
>
> **Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:**
>
> Always use complete class names

```html
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
```

> As long as you always use complete class names in your code, Tailwind will generate all of your CSS perfectly every time.

[source](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth=)

Comment: Can you not force the compiling of entire classes by declaring variants in `tailwind.config.js` ? Like `variants: { width: ['responsive'] }` seems to include/compile ALL sizes for breakpoints. ----- Or, as another way, make an invisible dummy element that has all the potential classes you may need in a given context.