# Alternative add programatically generated Tailwind classes (Vue, Nuxt)

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71779219/programmatically-craft-tailwind-classes-with-vue) and article inside. It's not possible with Tailwind CSS to programatically generate dynamic classes.

What's the alternative If my usecase must be dynamic? I have a progress bar div with a primary background and a span with dynamic progress coming from the api. I want to set a width class on the span like the following

```
<script setup>
  const items = [...] // Data
  const getWidthClass = (progressValue) => `'w-[${progressValue}]'`;
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="item in items" class="bg-red-500">
    <p class="bg-green-500" :class="getWidthClass(item.progressValue)" />
   <div/>
</template>
```

The utility class (`w-[50%]` for example) is added correctly but it has no styles as the questions explained.

Comment: Bind style attribute instead or [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) whole range of used percentage class (0-100 with defined step)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka no, don't safelist it. No point in using Tailwind otherwise...

Comment: Use this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585

Comment: @kissu totally agreed about not to safelisting but still this is an option to consider. Switch/case will create same problem here as safelisting - too many variants (at least 100 with step 1% or even more). I would use style attribute as it will cause no problem at all

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka not sure how it will be a problem. UnoCSS can maybe be more adapted but not really different. If the issue is to create a few variants, that could be automated.

Comment: @kissu I'm already doing what's mentioned in the link. So there isn't a better way than writing a 100 switch case?

Comment: While using Tailwind? Not my knowledge. The limitation is explicit: full-sized classes without interpolation. The switch cases can be generated ahead of time rather than done manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the 'ahead of time' part? I dont get it. Please do it in an answer to choose it and close the question

Comment: You can create an object by looping on it and accessing it's key, so that you get the full class out of it.

Comment: Okay thank you didn't know that this what ahead of time means