# Tailwind colors in brackets not working dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I recently ran into an issue that my custom colors are not working whenever I make them dynamically. I will provide 2 codes and 2 screenshots, one with the dynamical code, one with the dynamical output, one with the static code and one with the static output.

I refuse to acutally program them statically because I get that information from a seperate file that can change easily so it's easier for me to add one instead of creating a whole new divset.

Dynamic:

```
<div className='w-full bg-bgWhite'>
        <div className='w-1/2 grid grid-rows-3 gap-10 grid-cols-3'>
          {skills.map((skill, index) => (
            <div className={`p-5`}>
              {createElement(skill.icon.type, {
                className: `w-20 h-20`,
              })}
              <p className={`text-[${skill.color}]`}>{skill.color}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Dynamic output:
[image]

Static:

```
<div className='w-full bg-bgWhite'>
        <div className='w-1/2 grid grid-rows-3 gap-10 grid-cols-3'>
          {skills.map((skill, index) => (
            <div className={`p-5`}>
              {createElement(skill.icon.type, {
                className: `w-20 h-20`,
              })}
              <p className={`text-[#3FB27F]`}>{skill.color}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Static output:
[image]

**QUICK SIDENOTE**
Whenever I reset the code back to the dynamical form after executing the static form I get this solution:
[image]

This is gone after restarting the project.

Help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically craft Tailwind classes with Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71779219/programmatically-craft-tailwind-classes-with-vue)

Comment: I don't utilize Vue

Comment: it does not matter. You cannot programmatically construct tailwind classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Tailwind class names should be extracted at build-time, you cannot use string concatenation for generating a class name with a dynamic arbitrary.

So `text-[${skill.color}]` won't work.

You can change `color` property's value as `text-[#3FB27F]` in your object then it will work.

```js
const skills = [
  {
    text: "JS",
    color: "text-[#3FB27F]",
  },
  {
    text: "C#",
    color: "text-[#6A1577]",
  },
  {
    text: "React",
    color: "text-[#61DBFB]",
  },
  {
    text: "MySQL",
    color: "text-[#00618B]",
  },
 // ...
];

{skills.map((skill, index) => (
  <div className={`p-5`}>
    {createElement(skill.icon.type, {
      className: `w-20 h-20`,
    })}
    <p className={skill.color}>{skill.color}</p>
  </div>
))}
```

Or you can create a new array with `map` to then loop with another `map` without touching your original `color` value in DB or wherever you get that:

```js
skills
  .map((skill) => ({ ...skill, colorClass: `text-[${skill.color}]` }))
  .map((skill, index) => (
    <div key={index} className={`p-5`}>
      {createElement(skill.icon.type, {
        className: `w-20 h-20`,
      })}
      <p className={skill.colorClass}>{skill.color}</p>
    </div>
  ));
```

**Suggestion:** I didn't see `key` attribute in your loop. So don't forget to add it. If possible, don't use `index`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to active [`just-in-time`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-to-the-jit-engine) mode.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  // ...
}
```

with [`safelisting classes`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)

```
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    'text-2xl',
    'text-3xl',
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue)-(100|200|300)/,
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't change

Answer (score 0):

Apparently postcss makes this impossible, the only solution is adding them in tailwind config